# DataValueField pass value to repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

So if the user selects a value from a dropDownList and clicks the button, the ID is passed to the code behind(which is where I want it)
E.g.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataTextField="Company_Name" DataValueField="id">
<asp:ListItem Text="---Select---" Value="0" />   
</asp:DropDownList>
```

So dataValueField will pass the 'id' of the selected record in the DD.

However On the same page I am using a repeater to display records that have been previously chosen from the drop down, Beside each record i have a 'Change Prices' button which I want to perform a task when clicked, all works fine however all I need is the same 'id'.
So is this done in a similar way? E.g

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterShowName" runat="server">             
                <HeaderTemplate>                   
                        <tr>

                            <th>
                                <asp:Label ID="SubConName" Text="Current SubContractors" runat="server"></asp:Label>                               
                            </th>
                        </tr>                   
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="SubCon" Text='<%# Bind ("Company_Name")  %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>  
                        </td> 
                        <td>                                     
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="AddNewBOQLink" runat="server"  OnClick="EditPricesForSubContractor" CssClass="bottomhyperlink">Change Prices</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

//So Do I add in DataValueField="id" inside the link button, so when the user selects the hyperlink beside the name, it will automatically have the 'id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `CommandArgument` property of the LinkButton to pass the id to the method that handles the click.

So your `LinkButton` will now look like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="AddNewBOQLink" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("id")%>'  CssClass="bottomhyperlink">Change Prices</asp:LinkButton>
```

And you want to add the following property to your Repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater .... OnItemCommand="repeater_Command" ...
```

The method that will handle the command event will look like this

```
void repeater_Command(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {        
   //retrieve the id like so
   int id = (int)e.CommandArgument;
}
```

Also, note that I removed the `OnClick` property from the LinkButton. It is not needed as you are handling the click via the repeater's `OnItemCommand` method.

In addition, you may want to consider adding a `CommandName` propery to the LinkButton. This is used to identify which command you wish to execute. Currently, you only have a single command: Change Prices. But in the future you may want to add an additional button with a different command.

In order to do this, add the following property to the LinkButton:

```
<asp:LinkButton ... CommandName="ChangePrice" ...
```

And modify the `repeater_Command` method to handle the `CommandName`. Like so:

```
void repeater_Command(Object Sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e) {    
   switch(e.CommandName)
   {
      case "ChangePrice":    
         //retrieve the id like so
         int id = (int)e.CommandArgument;
         break;
   }
}
```